# How to plot two very large vectors

Tags: r, vector, plot

I've been trying to plot two very large vectors with about 4500 elements each. 
Let's say we have a vector a, which contains dates in the form of YYYYMMDD, vector b contains values

```
a = (19960101,......,20161231)
b = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,.....,0.5) 5000 elements between 0 and 1
```

I tried to plot these vectors, used xlab=a, ylab=y, but sadly it didn't work out as wished. I also tried to use smoothScatter(), but still no result.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: first convert your a into date time, then you will be fine

Comment: @yosemite_k how do I do this?

Comment: I warmly recommend E.Zivot's Working with Financial Time Series Data in R  https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/Working%20with%20Time%20Series%20Data%20in%20R.pdf

Comment: You did not present these vectors in a form that was R code. Makes experienced useRs wonder if you can even handle the basics of I/O. We don't know in what form these data are currently stored.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first convert `a` as date. make sure that a and b lengths are equal.

```
plot(as.Date(a),b)
```

If your date is in the format 'mmddyyyy' proceed as follows:

```
plot(as.Date(a,"%m%d%y"),b)
```

Based on your updated data format you can use gsub , Look at the following working example:

```
a <- c("19960101", "20161212")
b <- c(0.1,0.2)
a <- gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$","\\1-\\2-\\3",as.character(a))
plot(as.Date(a),b)
```

EDIT:
can directly use `plot(as.Date(a,"%Y%m%d),b)`  thanks @ben

Comment: does it also work if the dates are not seperated by /? e.g. 01011996

Comment: yes, you can use the second option `plot(as.Date(a,"%m%d%y"),b)`

Comment: It says: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format, I also tried to change it to "%Y%m%d", since the dates inside the vector are not seperated by a /, they look like this: 20140101

Comment: update your question with the correct data format you have

Comment: is it yearMonthDate or yearDateMonth?

Comment: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format, again the same error message

Comment: should that be `"%Y%m%d"` (uppercase Y)?

Comment: I figured it out I think. I converted both a and b to factors, used an uppercase Y in the code and it worked actually. Problem is, the plot doesn't look that nice at all. How can I scale down the y-axis to between 0 and 1 values?

Comment: you should ask that in a new thread stating what kind of plot you need and your initial attempt. you can accept this as answer to your question